# How to make a Container inside a Row take all the vertical height available?

Tags: flutter

I've the following layout:

[image]

So this is like a custom ListTile, where the height of the ListTile depends on the text it is having. So what I want is that when the text grows, the image container also expands accordingly to fill in all the available height.

**This is the current code:**

```
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: ColorsApp.line_vertical_grey.withOpacity(.2),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            // TODO: FIX THIS CONTAINER IMAGE, FILL THE HEIGHT
            child: Container(
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                child: Image.network(
                  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589198360919-1fb67e42bda5?q=80&w=1000&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTl8fGZpbmQlMjB5b3Vyc2VsZnxlbnwwfHwwfHx8MA%3D%3D',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          'HR Genius',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 6, vertical: 2),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: ColorsApp.black,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          'HR',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 10,
                            color: ColorsApp.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Dicta velit consequatur beatae. Nisi ad eligendi in incidunt blanditiis sed dolorum. Et unde quam blanditiis ab dolor atque.',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                    maxLines: 3,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

**And this is the current behaviour**

[image]

Comment: try *IntrinsicHeight. For ur purpose.  1. IntrinsicHeight( child: Row())   2. use Container( child: BoxDecoration( image :)) instead Image.network   3. remove Text's *maxLine & *textOverFlow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [crossAxisAlignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flex/crossAxisAlignment.html) of the `Row` to `stretch`. This way, every child of the `Row` will be stretched to the vertical axis (which is the cross axis of a `Row`).

```dart
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  // ...
)
```

If you need other individual child to stay centered without being stretched, wrap it with `Center(...)`.

---

Articles related to `Flex`, alignments, and constraints:

- [Aligning widgets](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout#aligning-widgets)
- [Understanding constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints)

Comment: Doesn't work. It needs a fixed height on the parent to make this work.

Comment: Exactly. Because you want the height to fill all the vertical height available, the parent widget must have a constraint for its height (not necessarily a fixed number). Otherwise, it's not possible.

Comment: Ah okay! I'll go with a fixed height then. Thank you